# Apache Zeppelin - note scope input forms error

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I want to use dynamic input forms as note scope in paragraph.

It succeeds in case of paragraph scope, but fails in case of note scope.

I am using zeppelin 0.10.0

No problem in 0.8.0

What's the problem?

e.g.) note scope input form
`select * from student where name = '$${name}'`

zeppelin server error log:
On the log, the name input form is well bound.

```
select * from student where name = 'jack'
WARN [2021-12-15 14:02:54,384] ({SchedulerFactory75} PooledRemoteClient.java[releaseBrokenClient]:80) - release broken client
DEBUG [2021-12-15 14:02:54,385] ({SchedulerFactory75} AbstractScheduler.java[runJob]:145) - Job Error, paragraph_1638522886721_1389765663, %text java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.PooledRemoteClient.callRemoteFunction(PooledRemoteClient.java:114)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:99)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:208)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:486)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:71)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:132)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:182)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more of a workaround than a fix, and my error was slightly different, but on Zeppelin 0.9.0 in order to use note scope dynamic input forms I had to provide a default value the first time the input was used:

```
select * from student where name = '$${name=example_name}'
```

Try deleting your form input and then run the paragraph again with the default value provided and then change the input to 'jack' after it has run with the default value one time.

Comment: thank you.
I entered the default value as you said, but no error occurred.